# Check if an expression compiles including all implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, compile-time, static-assert

Consider the following code:

```
void f(auto& i, auto& j)
{
    static_assert(/* SOMETHING */, "");
    // function body here...
}
```

I want the `/* SOMETHING */` part to check whether the following code compiles (taking into account all the standard rules, like implicit conversion rules):

```
i += j;
```

I tried:

```
sizeof(std::declval<decltype(i)>() += std::declval<decltype(j)>());
```

but it fails.

What is the correct way to do it?

Edit: I know about SFINAE and constraining template parameters. This is not the topic of the question. The topic is how to make a `static_assert` fails while testing the correctness of an expression.

Comment: The best you can query is "is this expression well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand", not "will this expression compile".

Comment: @T.C. In this case, there is no effective difference between these statements, AFAICS.

Comment: @Columbo Think of a `+=` template whose body doesn't compile.

Comment: @T.C. Good point. I missed that the instantiation of that template is not necessitated in the unevaluated operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to define a corresponding trait and employ that in the assertion. E.g.

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename=void> struct check : std::false_type{};
template <typename A, typename B>
struct check<A, B, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<A&>() += std::declval<B&>())>>
    : std::true_type{};
```

Or, if concepts are available,

```
template <typename A, typename B>
concept bool check = requires (A& a, B& b) {a += b;};
```

Comment: I didn't know `auto` function parameters were allowed in standard C++ (outside lambdas, I mean)

Comment: @Brian They aren't right now, but the Concepts TS, which will be included in C++1Z, makes it valid (and GCC implemented the auto-in-parameters bit for 4.9)